# How to retrieve dropdown options list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, jsom

I'm using JS to create application based on SharePoint.

**What I have:** 
field in list item, with dropdown and few values that are not list (just few static values). I suppose this dropdown created using some special magic of SP UI.

**What I can't figure out**:
how to retrieve this options for droplist using REST or JSOM to create my own dropdown but with same values.

I can hardcode it right now, but you know why it's not a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SharePoint, I assumed that Column type is "Choice field".

Below is the code for get all choices from that choice field:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Site URL"+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results[0].Choices.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

Reference Link : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/18defe52-d211-4720-993b-5e6197457e20/how-to-get-choice-fields-values-using-rest-api-or-jsom?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Using REST API, you can try below code which relies on the display name of the choice column:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://sitecollectionurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/fields/getbytitle('ChoiceField')",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results[0].ChoiceField.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

**Option 2** - using JSOM

```
var distinctChoices = [];
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('CustomList');
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("ChoiceFieldName");
var choiceField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.FieldChoice);

ctx.load(field);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () { 
    distinctChoices = choiceField.get_choices();        
},
function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args);
});
```

Reference - [Get choice field using JSOM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/18defe52-d211-4720-993b-5e6197457e20/how-to-get-choice-fields-values-using-rest-api-or-jsom?forum=sharepointdevelopment)